# Multi-input LSTM model using Keras Functional API

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

[image: Model]

I have variable-length words which are represented as vectors of boolean vectors.
For ex: CAR is represented as

```
[[0,0,1,0,...,0],[[1,0,0,0,...,0]],[0,0,...,0,1,...]]
      ^            ^                          ^
      C            A                          R
```

It is one of the inputs to the model with another flat input vector.

While trying to fit the model, I get an error

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 3, 26
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

How to create an input layer using the Functional API of Keras to facilitate variable-length inputs to LSTM?

Current Model:

```
def gen_LSTM_model():
    obscured_word_input = Input(shape=(None,27,))
    letters_guessed_correctly_input = Input(shape=(26,))
    final_lstm_output = LSTM(MAX_WORD_LEN, return_sequences=False)(obscured_word_input)
    merged = Concatenate(axis=1)([final_lstm_output, letters_guessed_correctly_input])
    dense_layer = Dense(26, input_dim=2)(merged)
    
    lstm_model = Model(inputs=[obscured_word_input, letters_guessed_correctly_input], outputs=dense_layer)
    return lstm_model

model = gen_LSTM_model()
model.compile()
plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

Comment: What is your call to model.fit and the shape of all the inputs passed to fit?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I'm trying to implement reinforcement learning. I haven't figured it out yet, but firstly with a datapoint, I need to get a predicted value. 

In the calling function, it contains an input of dim(3,27) and the second branch input contains a dim(26,)

Comment: Sorry but that does not answer anything of what I asked, if you use a single data point, it is likely you have incorrect shapes. Note that there is nothing wrong in the model setup, seems the problem is how you are fitting it.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy In the calling function, it contains an input of dim(3,27) and the second branch input contains a dim(26,)

Comment: Good, now the problem is clear, even for a single example, you need to add the batch dimension to all the inputs (1, 3, 27) and (1, 26). Then you will different issues due to the concatenation not always being possible, but that is a different problem.